# Entity Id Across Multiple Orgs

Tags: salesforce-id, id

I have created a package and in it I have two custom objects foo__c and bar__c. My question is can I assume that their entity id (the first 3 digits of their id) is the same across all of the Orgs that use my package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Behavior of custom object prefix ID when using Change Sets**

[Knowledge Article Number: 000176809](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176809&language=en_US)

Depending on the type of Sandbox you are using, a custom object prefix ID might change upon deploying it on a target organization. This article gives all the possible scenarios and their outcome.

Resolution

The list below assumes you are transferring a Change Set from a Sandbox to another Sandbox or a Production instance.

If you transfer a Change Set from

- Developer Sandbox to Full Sandbox
- Developer to Production.
- Configuration to Full Sandbox
- Configuration to Configuration Sandbox.
- Configuration To Production.
- Full Sandbox to Developer Sandbox
- Full Sandbox to Configuration Sandbox.

The custom object ID Prefix will be different. Salesforce will generate a new custom object ID.

If you transfer a Change Set from

- Full Sandbox to Production
- Configuration to Developer sandbox.
- Developer to Configuration Sandbox.
- Developer to Developer Sandbox

The custom object ID Prefix will remain the same.

Comment: That is what I figured since a Production org can have multiple packages.

Answer (score 3):

When a managed package is installed, the 3 digit prefix of a custom object will vary: the values are allocated perhaps on a "first custom object created" basis and so will vary from org to org.

So in your code you should not assume a fixed value but instead use e.g. [DescribeSObjectResult.getKeyPrefix()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_getKeyPrefix) or grab the first 3 characters of an ID that you know is of the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  The package runs in your context.

The first 3 digit will be same across all the organisation where your package is installed.